# In what sense const allows only atomic changes to mutable member variables?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, constants, atomic, mutable

I'm reading Functional Programming in C++ from [Ivan Čukić](https://cukic.co/), and I am having a hard time interpreting a point in the summary of Chapter 5:

> - When you make a member function `const`, you promise that the function won't change any data in the class (not a bit of the object will change), or that any changes to the object *(to members declared as `mutable`) will be atomic as far as the users of the object are concerned*.

If the part in *italic* was simply *are limited to members declared as `mutable`* I would have been happy with it. However, this rewording of mine seems to correspond to what the author put in parenthesis. What is out of parenthesis is what is puzzling me: what is the meaning of *atomic* in that sentence?

Comment: Watch this Herb Sutter's presentation: [C++ and Beyond 2012: Herb Sutter - You don't know `const` and `mutable`](https://channel9.msdn.com/posts/C-and-Beyond-2012-Herb-Sutter-You-dont-know-blank-and-blank).

Comment: @Evg, thank you for the suggestion. Maybe I'll be able to self answer after watching that, if none else gives a good answer before.

Comment: @EnricoMariaDeAngelis, in that video Herb Sutter argues that in C++11 `const` and `mutable` are inherently related to thread safety. This is a subtle issue, so I just posted that link instead of trying to summarize the video in an answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The author is making a claim about best practices, not about the rules of the language.

You *can* write a class in which `const` methods alter `mutable` members in ways that are visible to the user, like this:

```
struct S {
    mutable int value = 0;
    int get() const {
        return value++;
    }
};
const S s;
std::cout << s.get();  // prints 0
std::cout << s.get();  // prints 1
// etc
```

You can do that, and it wouldn't break any of the rules of the language. However, you *shouldn't*. It violates the user's expectation that the `const` method should not change the internal state in an observable way.

There are legitimate uses for `mutable` members, such as memoization that can speed up subsequent executions of a `const` member function.

The author suggests that, as a matter of best practices, such uses of `mutable` members by `const` member functions *should* be atomic, since users are likely to *expect* that two different threads can call `const` member functions on an object concurrently.

If you violate this guideline, then you're not directly breaking any rules of the language. However, it makes it likely that users will use your class in a way that will cause data races (which are undefined behaviour). It takes away the user's ability to use the `const` qualifier to reason about the thread-safety of your class.

Answer (score 3):

> or that any changes to the object (to members declared as mutable)
>   will be atomic as far as the users of the object are concerned.

I think the author (or editor) of the book worded his statement poorly there -- `const` and `mutable` make no guarantees about thread-safety; indeed, they were part of the language back when the language had no support for multithreading (i.e. back when multithreading specifications were not part of the C++ standard and therefore anything you did with multithreading in your C++ program was therefore technically undefined behavior).

I think what the author intended to convey is that changes to mutable member-variables from with a const-tagged method should be limited only to changes that don't change the object's state *as far as the calling code can tell*.  The classic example of this would be memo-ization of an expensive computation for future reference, e.g.:

```
class ExpensiveResultGenerator
{
public:
    ExpensiveResultGenerator()
       : _cachedInputValue(-1)
    {
    }

    float CalculateResult(int inputValue) const
    {
       if ((_cachedInputValue < 0)||(_cachedInputValue != inputValue))
       {
          _cachedInputValue = inputValue;
          _cachedResult     = ReallyCPUExpensiveCalculation(inputValue);
       }
       return _cachedResult;
    }

private:
    float ReallyCPUExpensiveCalculation(int inputValue) const
    {
        // Code that is really expensive to calculate the value
        // corresponding to (inputValue) goes here....
        [...]
        return computedResult;
    }

    mutable int _cachedInputValue;
    mutable float _cachedResult;
}
```

Note that as far as the code using the `ExpensiveResultGenerator` class is concerned, `CalculateResult(int) const` doesn't change the state of the `ExpensiveResultGenerator` object; it is simply computing a mathematical function and returning the result.  But internally we are making a memo-ization optimization so that if the user calls `CalculateResult(x)` with the same value for `x` multiple times in a row, we can skip the expensive calculation after the first time and just return the `_cachedResult` instead, for a speedup.

Of course, making that memo-ization optimization can introduce race conditions in a multi-threaded environment, since now we are changing state variables even if the calling code can't see us doing it.  So to do this safely in a multithreaded environment, you would need to employ a Mutex of some sort to serialize accesses to the two mutable variables -- either that, or require the calling code to serialize any calls to `CalculateResult()`.

Comment: I guess the author's point was not that `const` and `mutable` themselves make guarantees, but that code should be written in a way so that `const` and `mutable` are thread-safe by design. It is your promise.